# Does Crashlytics works in China?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have added Firebase Crashlytics into my project. I was wondering the service available in China? Since Crashlytics formally owned by Fabric and now has been owned by Firebase. Not sure China will prevent Crashlytics from working.